# Pandas convert rows to column based on count

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown

[image]

I need to convert it like this

[image]

This is just sample dummy replica of my actual data .. It has over 5000 ID'd and 20 Events.

So I need for each ID , sum of how many times each event where triggered individually and events need to be separate columns.How to achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used pandas pivot_table function

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                       'two','one','three'],
               'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C','A','A'],
               'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,1,2],
               'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't','x','x']})
print(df)
    bar  baz  foo   zoo
0   A    1    one   x
1   B    2    one   y
2   C    3    one   z
3   A    4    two   q
4   B    5    two   w
5   C    6    two   t
6   A    1    one   x
7   A    2  three   x

df.pivot_table(index='foo',columns='bar',values='baz',aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)

bar    A    B   C
foo         
one    2    1   1
three  1    0   0
two    1    1   1
```

In this case you might have to do like below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event':['a','b','c','d','c','a','a'],'ID':['001','002','003','004','004','004','001']})
df = df.reset_index()
df.pivot_table(index='ID',columns='Event',values='index',aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)
Event   a   b   c   d
ID              
001     2   0   0   0
002     0   1   0   0
003     0   0   1   0
004     1   0   1   1
```

Comment: Hi , I tried pivot table but I am unable to get the result image I showed you.

Comment: could you please tell me what the code would be for my case in case I am typing it wrong.